# Is there a formalization of absolute geometry?

Tags: geometry, logic

I am trying to formalize absolute geometry, and it means the following:

I want to express the axioms through of symbols only, and make the proofs by means of inference rules and definitions. I don't want words in my proofs, I only want symbols, every proof will be a complete proof.

But I am having many problems with this, so I thought that maybe someone has tried the same than me, and, Indeed, my question is related with that.

Is there a formalization of abslute geometry?

Now, If it's the case, where can I find it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms

Comment: The Tarski's and Hilbert's geometries are suitable for formalization of neutral geometry (common part of Hyberbolic and Euclidean) but are not suitable for the formalization of absolute geometry because they imply the existence of parallel lines, so they can not deal with spherical geometry.

Answer (score 3):

[Absolute geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_geometry) can be formalized using [Hilbert's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) without the parallel axiom.

A complete formalization of Euclidean geometry in the [Coq proof assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq) is given in [1], a thesis in which you will find further references. It covers Hilbert's axioms and Tarski's axioms and the relations between them. You might also be interested in [2], which makes use of the interactive theorem prover ELFE.

[1] P. Boutry, [On the formalization of foundations of geometry](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-02166221/document), Thesis, Université de Strasbourg, France, 2018.

[2] M. Doré and K. Broda, [Towards Intuitive Reasoning in Axiomatic Geometry](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.01006.pdf), THedu@FLoC 2018: 38-55

**Table of Contents of [1]** (extract)

Part I. Foundations of Euclidean Geometry 9
Chapter I.1. Tarski’s System of Geometry: a Theory for Euclidean Geometry 13

1. Formalization of Tarski’s Axioms 13
2. Satisfiability of the Theory 17
3. The Arithmetization of Tarski’s System of Geometry 20

Chapter I.2. Hilbert’s axioms: a Theory Mutually Interpretable with Tarski’s System of Geometry 25

1. Formalization of Hilbert’s Axioms 25
2. Proving that Tarski’s Axioms follow from Hilbert’s 31

Chapter I.3. Metatheorems about Tarski’s System of Geometry 37

1. Independence of Euclid’s Parallel Postulate via Herbrand’s Theorem 37
2. Towards the Decidability of Every First-Order Formula 43

Conclusion of Part I